# 2 recordset in dreamweaver with mysql DB could not be linked

Tags: php, html, mysql

My DB has 2 tables `mp_details` (unique id `id`) and `pic_gal` (unique ID `pic_id`).

`pic_gal` has a field `mp_name` which recieves
the value of mp_details `id` in the master admin page when the link to
visit is clicked the result is supposed to be like this

```
http://localhost/win-bengal/test-mp-details-new.php?id=['id']&mp_name=['mp_name']
```

e.g.

```
http://localhost/win-bengal/test-mp-details-new.php?id=1&mp_name=1 it
```

works fine for the first link but then onwards the problem starts

```
localhost/win-bengal/test-mp-details-new.php?id=2&mp_name=1
```

how ever
when this 1 is changed to 2 manualy the desired result is achieved. So
in other words 'mp_name' is returning just the first value. Please
help

This is the first Recordset which pull all the user information

```
mysql_select_db($database_mp_db, $mp_db);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM mp_details";
$query_limit_Recordset1 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_Recordset1, $startRow_Recordset1, $maxRows_Recordset1);
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_limit_Recordset1, $mp_db) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
```

This is the second Recordset which pulls information about picture

```
mysql_select_db($database_mp_db, $mp_db);
$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT * FROM pic_gal";
$Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2, $mp_db) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
$totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset2);
```

This query is supposed to act as a bridge between the 2 tables where id of table mp_details is equal to mp_name of table pic_gal

```
$query = "SELECT mp_details.*, pic_gal.* ".
"FROM mp_details, pic_gal ".
"WHERE mp_details.id = pic_gal.mp_name";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>ADMIN HOME</title>
<link href="../css/css-admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<p> <a href="add_data.php">Add Record</a> | <a href="../photo-gallery/admin/index.php">upload Image</a></p>
<table width="75%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#A9C8CB"><strong>id</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#A9C8CB"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#A9C8CB"><strong>District</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#A9C8CB"><strong>Phone</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#A9C8CB"><strong>Email</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#A9C8CB">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#A9C8CB">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#A9C8CB">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#A9C8CB">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="../test-mp-details-new.php?id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']?>&mp_name=*<?php echo $row_Recordset2['mp_name']; ?>*" target="_blank"><img src="../images/mp_photos/<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['name']; ?>" width="" height="" border="0" title="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['name']; ?>" /><br /><?php echo $row_Recordset1['name']; ?></a></td>

</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);

mysql_free_result($Recordset2);
?>
```

here

> < ? php echo $row_Recordset2['mp_name']; ? >

is supposed to echo the same value ad 'id' but it isn't happening so. it only echos the first value

Comment: We are not going to read through a wall of bad code to try and GUESS where your problem is.

Comment: thanks for your response all I needed was help so I posted the code so that some one might help me

Comment: I have simplified the code @Uli Köhler

Comment: take a look & i will be really obliged if you could suggest a solution @UliKöhler